# Try to understand why i'm having an unexpected UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY error

Tags: javascript, npm

When I `npm ls react-dom` it returns on my project the following graph

```
package1@28.4.0 /Volumes/Workspace/package1_WT/dev
├─┬ @storybook/components@5.1.11
│ └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@16.14.0 
├─┬ @storybook/react@5.1.11
│ └─┬ @storybook/core@5.1.11
│   └─┬ @storybook/ui@5.1.11
│     └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@16.14.0 
├─┬ randomPackage@12.21.1
│ └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@17.0.2  deduped
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@17.0.2
```

The package.json is having declared as a dependency (not as a peerDependency) "react-dom": "~17.0.0". Actually when checking the node_modules, version 17.0.2 of react-dom is installed which actually falls into the range of "~17.0.0".

Why is it returning an UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@17.0.2 error for the root package.json ? while it actually make sense for the storybook packages

Answer (score 1):

The version of Storybook (specifically `@storybook/components` and `@storybook/ui`) that you have installed say they depend on `react-dom@16.14.0`.

`react-dom@17.0.2` is a different major version.

You've got a conflict between what your main package depends on directly and what it depends on indirectly via Storybook.

You can probably resolve this by upgrading Storybook

Comment: so it would throw an error at everything while only storybook react-dom dependencies are concerned ?